# Saving a file using the ContentType with a valid file extension

Tags: angularjs, post

I want to be able to save a file via an Http POST with a valid file extension.

I can't use the contentType because it's not a valid file extension.

I'm trying to do this with an AngularsJS http post.

Note the last line in the code. How can I give the file a proper extension instead of hard coding it?

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var fileName = attrs.downloadType + "_" + attrs.downloadId;
    var contentType = headers('Content-Type');
    var file = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
    saveAs(file, fileName + '.txt');
})
```

Comment: what are you using in `attrs.downloadType` ? Seems like that would provide detail you need to assign extension

Comment: That is just a variable from the application in the attribute field.

Comment: That's not much of an explanation, am fully aware it is an attribute value....what sort of values does it use?

Answer (score 0):

Create a conversion function:

```
function extConvert(contentType) {
    var extHash = { "text/plain": "txt",
                    "application/json": "json"
                  }
    return extHash[contentType] || "txt";
};
```

Then use it in your code:

```
httpPromise.then(function onFulfilled(response) {
    var fileName = attrs.downloadType + "_" + attrs.downloadId;
    var contentType = response.headers('Content-Type');
    var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });
    var ext = extConvert(contentType);
    FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName + '.' + ext');
});
```

### Additional Resources

- [Apache Mime Type List](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup)
- [Angular File Saver on GitHub](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver#angular-file-saver)

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>